# Best approach to control terraform similar resources without re-creating them when a list is modified

Tags: terraform

Consider the code below:

```
variable "list" {
  type = "list"
  default = ["a", "b", "c"]
}

resource "null_resource" "resources_from_a_list" {
  count = "${length(var.list)}"
  triggers {
    field = "${element(var.list, count.index)}}"
  }
}
```

In terraform, it is commom to use a loop count to create similar resources.

When it is necessary to modify this list, removing the first item, for example:

```
var.list from ["a", "b", "c"] to  ["b", "c"]
```

All resources are recreated because it is the index that controls the creation/destruction of resources.

What is the best approach to not recreate them if one of the items is removed from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform 0.12 will solve this problem with the new `for_each` construct.

Currently there are only hacky workarounds like editing the tfstate:

```
terraform state mv <resource-name>.<resource-id>[<i>] <resource-name>.<resource-id>[<j>]
```

More discussion here - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14275

Another option is to use external templating like jinja templates whereby the source tf itself is a jinja template and the resources are created as individual resource blocks using the templating constructs.